# An unfamiliar logo "uap" on the DVD label

Tags: merchandise

What logo is this? It's printed on an anime's DVD label. Reverse image search shows [this](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiv8Qk2v7-IEIvxPNDxd36wizRGouABpO32bIMbrMg0F48Z8_1Yy5eC_1ceFdwf8e8o1mh17cjwH_1oC9RNgTg6hszKfzQwnqf4_13ZnFjkYxVqPMvi-b8BTnwo3EWkoiTU9VBKaykp2iXJdvlnn0e8lwZzTVDqtK50zEPrl_1vojEUYfReXQjhP_1f-8CDTYlw2tF96dmc5RU1BX--e-oVE8m25r2lcedgN0tShCnJ-Vaeoj0sPhd9QZqgmJRnfCrUD-UZPk_1q1tUiy7OKV0tIk5xxKd5gtQJN94OpzxyzyufdNeQlKWB1Wy745FoqargTRcANu2n72KtOOFoGllNSDdKX3oIA_12arLCnfyy4m69I0ZmkZXgU9RW9h_1UEneP5rsv2NCyuyjp_1l58-PZdZQ-gtnms_1eg79QqJUzxJIgn7FVnSY-M3C4DL5zAUE41BxRLwS9dLo1UTBdrV8n_1YTA4XmQXu718pQXZX_1FI-kiAucSrZem8rsHXr8CzdnkMwN4Vo18HdZptcW2j8CHWGCYqz_1lB2Xma-NqpkG-hvcAFbiAnmrpevtcvFd5SvyY9njq1GNbU9hVvPmOU8zButizX3X-DTrTyQ5kXVFnT9kXt_1T3XgnwXDOMDCcHOCV9WRUNLlg5nNdlvORqmSOqwrjqvVAtO2Rrj3GN3P3sv3yKeumZRtRjJrZB-rh36J0Z7i1NL-LQ9jToEcUajGTn1rfPzRClb7F-Kvlxlr2X6X6sIWmbiDVft7VdD4t2TLzgIh2mFl0abh1WirlHOhhWriX1zTK5z3tSDoSbPseHxNXhs2_1ihMyFfCwYisJXllVFHUApoEZaRRiEu_1oJBvvjE7qwPYGIzhkUu3xeMOuzrJLFO6XHqiZWl195AiVevgeiyzcd2ULcEghHb18MAGgypPeOnwpnp1ITzNIuCckNjrSSgG29DZdIveRvaG7YqvsLg_1OAuC3EVkiaR9kYppZSJ_1UAFdSJ_1dtlEHmx2n8RZF48N7Pdc9W9VlRreI9gKYou85Gg3oHutJiVjZ9NJV0Js1DJZ0PunNJtP_1m2ZnDP3pTs3AOovMkLuP2spivhFkOx6ygliXRD7S90nKnPHaATZHnpDfAdGVZb1UCWDTt-vLQYaxKJyd90hsnfZw3UxMGoV7KNsVANljt6vwsFCt-pgkQkJK7N5Nr2nyAjtf5hZ1_1iyg5qsScd4E3RLszfYxPLgMol56lK4kzku4RgCxVk9O-NuQnZ5YAG2Tb5qJAcFkHkqaIYbob1nBIaGtRgyRZxXP642z7zOkXBEQw1zk3SfH3AKqlbyN3lNB94dQcBAt-uZll9x3Z29FsIWWDp7cCtMDaeVTZoeGlvYLjUiLaRhQPBoI6FsEbGxOI2g), anyone knows this logo?
[image]

Comment: It's [vap](http://www.vap.co.jp/smart/main/main.html), not "uap"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe VAP is what that actually is. Their website is here: [***Vap***](http://www.vap.co.jp/), according to animenewsnetwork:

> VAP is a subsidiary of the NTV (Nippon Television Network) Group.

Here is the [***animenewsnetwork***](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/company.php?id=589) page that lists all of the anime's Vap has been involved with.

Comment: Simple answer, yet is what I want!

Answer (score 3):

Yes I know this logo it's from the **VAP entertainment company**.

It's not very clear from their Wikipedia or ANN page how many branches this company has and what they do exactly but they seem to be involved in broadcasting and obviously operating as a music label besides production or licensing and distribution of anime and games.

---

The logo is a [script typeface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_typeface) with [serifs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif) and [swashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swash_%28typography%29). In script the lower letter *v* is connected at the top where the lower letter *u* is connected at the bottom, similar to the *a*. That's how you usually can tell them apart.

[image]

Using reverse image search for fonts and logos can be tricky. While [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) shouldn't be a problem for OCR, these letters are melted together and baked into artifacts and noisy background.

Another option to avoid misinterpreting logos would be too look for product codes or [URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) on the disk or jacket and look these up instead of reverse image search.